# Unable to fetch data equal to 0

Tags: php, mysql

I have a small database that will show data being updated as 0 and not as 1. When I try to run the following sql query

Database PHP
    // Connect To DB
    $hostname="localhost";
    $database="xxxx";
    $username="xxxxx";
    $password="xxxxx";

```
@$conn = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password)
        or die("Could not connect to server " . mysql_error()); 
    mysqli_select_db($conn, $database)
        or die("Error: Could not connect to the database: " . mysql_error());

    /*Check for Connection*/
    if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
        // Display Error message if fails
        echo 'Error, could not connect to the database please try again again.';
    exit();
    }

$query = 'SELECT * FROM mods ORDER BY id where updated="0"';
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
@$num_results = mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

I have tried wrapping and not wrapping the 0 in '' and "".

Currently it just loads the HTML table without data. If I remove the where statement, it pulls fine.

HTML PHP

```
                             for($i=0; $i<$num_results; $i++) {
                                    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

                                    ?>


                                        <tr>



                                <td style=""><?php print $row['mod_name']; ?></td>
                                <td style=""><div id"tdcenter" style="width: 44px;white-space:nowrap;overflow: hidden;text-overflow: ellipsis;text-align:center;"><?php print $row['mod_version']; ?></div></td>
                                <td style=""><?php print $row['time']; ?></td>
                            </tr>
<?php 
// end loop
} 
?>
```

Comment: remove the double quotes of zero in select query and also move  ORDERBY clause after where clause.

Comment: @anantkumarsingh Same issue

Comment: put the 0 in a variable e.g `$value = 0` and insert it into the query

Comment: @danidee why would it need to be in a variable?

Comment: was just a suggestion instead of directly putting raw integer into the query

Comment: @Ryahn please up-vote also if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try these and check which one works for you:-

1. As @BigRabbit says :- $query = "SELECT * FROM mods ORDER BY id where updated='0'";
2. create a variable $update = 0;
   and now append it to your query $query = "SELECT * FROM mods ORDER BY id where updated=".$update;
3. Another attempt is swapping ORDERBY and WHERE clause.

Comment: Thank you, moving the ORDERBY to the end of the query resolved it.

Comment: thanks and i already stated in my first comment if you look.:)

Answer (score 1):

The syntax on your query is wrong try this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM mods ORDER BY id where updated='0'";
```